# Encrypt particular fields in a java class

Tags: java, encryption

I want to perform encryption on particular fields in the class let's say,

```
public class employeeDetail{

private String employeeID;

private String employeeContactNo; // this field will be encrypted

private String employeeAddress; // this field will be encrypted

private String employeeName;

}
```

I want to **encrypt some particular fields**, not all from the Java Object.

Can anyone please suggest a better way to achieve this?

**Note: This is not an entity.**

Comment: Strings are pretty hard to delete from memory in Java, so even if you encrypt the field you'd still be left with the information. I'd strongly suggest only to encrypt during storage of the object. Probably somebody will suggest UTF-8 encoding, followed by symmetric or asymmetric encryption, followed by base 64 encoding, which will convert the binary ciphertext back into a string. But it is highly doubtful that this will actually solve your problem.

Comment: What is your goal with encrypting fields? What are you hoping to guard against?

Comment: The goal here is, let's say there is some personal detail and I want to store the details, but not in a human-readable format.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.